# Looking for plugin to guide visitors through complicated site

Tags: html, plugins, navigation

I saw this plugin on a site recently and really like it. https://lpt.revenue.ie/lpt-web/views/login.html?execution=e1s1

Click on the small button on the bottom left that says "Help me with this page"

We have a very complicated process and we try to guide the user through each step of the process, but we are not doing as good a job as we should. Does anyone know of good plugins that can help a visitor to go through the various steps as they navigate a site, so that it highlights each step along the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[intro.js](http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/) may be what you would like

Comment: Thanks Nick, that is great! Robert Harvey, sorry will try to keep things less "Discussiony" and more about the problem at hand.